# Return row if it matches values, unless its unique identifier matches the wrong value

Tags: sql, t-sql

**Problem:**

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to return the following:

[image]

I want to return only groups of Project Categories where all projects within that category can only be a stage of Closed.

**What I've Tried:**
This is as far as I have gotten but it only produces a list of all projects that have a stage of closed, but I wanted to exclude project categories where any of its projects are not closed.

```
  SELECT Project_Category, Project, Stage, Reason
  FROM Table
  WHERE Project_Category IN (
    SELECT Project_Category
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY Project_Category
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Project) > 1
  )
  AND Stage = 'Closed'
  AND Reason = 'no award'
  ORDER BY Project_Category
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to return only groups of Project Categories where all projects within that category can only be a stage of Closed.

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.Project_Category = t.Project_Category and 
                        t2.Stage <> 'Closed'
                 )
```